# File system searching (C#) against specified file list

Tags: c#, search-engine

My client wants to add a file system searching feature in a B/S application based on C#. It is a little special that the search shall be in a scope of specified file list but not a whole directory with just certain file extension.

I did some research on Microsoft Office Sharepoint Server Search Service, but couldn't get a clue whether it supports searching against specific files. I'm now using it to search PDF files, but not the same case of what I'm asking for.

Can anyone give me some suggestions what 3rd party search service/engine I should take for the requirement?

Thanks.
Elaine

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are wanting full text indexing of a certain set of files?

Java has the best selection of libraries for this, but there are C# ports as well.

I highly recommend Lucene for indexing and retrieval.:
http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

If this is on a server, it might be easiest to run a Solr instance and use C# as the client:
http://crazorsharp.blogspot.com/2010/01/full-text-search-using-solr-lucene-and.html

Lucene has many examples on indexing different document types, but if you use Solr, it will handle that for you.